# Pic Won't Show Up on My AskUbuntu Profile After Uploading JPG File to My Profile

Tags: support, status-completed

I took the option to change picture on my Profile, and uploaded a 9KB JPG pic; but it's just showing a white screen where my pic should be.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see it now, I see an eagle next to your name.

Comment: Yeah this is probably just a caching thing

Comment: Yep.  It's there now.  Must've been.

Comment: How to make everyone look at your avatar